# How to handle discontinuities in implicit function plotting with GLSL?

Tags: glsl

I'm currently working on a GLSL program to create an implicit function plotter. Implicit functions are defined by equations of the form f(x, y) = 0. The plotter is working correctly for continuous input functions, but I'm facing difficulties when dealing with discontinuous functions.

I have implemented a pixel value assignment metric inspired by a blog post I found [here](https://iquilezles.org/articles/distance/) (would love to know the scientific name of this metric):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVHnv.png]

When the metric value is close to zero, the pixel should be on, and otherwise, it is off. To calculate the gradients, I'm using an auto-diff library available [here](https://github.com/sibaku/glsl-autodiff/blob/a51cab24c74c1ea2db374583cd8c637d7e7c47bf/grad_2.glsl).

To provide a more concrete example, I have created a contrived function on Shadertoy
[here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/dt3XDr). The function is defined as follows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmO93.png]

The resulting plot includes both the line y = 0 and the line x = 0. The function is discontinuous at x = 0, but I want the shader to only plot the line y = 0. Removing the x component and reducing the function to f(x, y) = y = 0 would solve this particular example, but I need a more general solution that can handle any arbitrary implicit function.

Here's the GLSL code I'm currently using:

```c
#define RGBA_RED   vec4(1., .4, .4, 1.)

#define SCALE 2.    // Range for the smallest axis!
#define THICK 4.    // Line thickness

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Drawing machinery!

// NSDF((val, gradient))
#define NSDF(gNum) (gNum.val / length(gNum.g))

// PLOT_IMPLICIT(function, pixel coordinate, color0, color1)
#define PLOT_IMPLICIT(f, p, c0, c1)  mix(c0, c1, smoothstep(.0, (THICK * SCALE / iResolution.y), abs(NSDF(f(p)))))

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

GNum2 curve(vec2 uv) {
    GNum2 x = varG2x(uv.x);
    GNum2 y = varG2y(uv.y);

    return div(x, y);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord){
    vec2 uv = SCALE * (2. * fragCoord - iResolution.xy) / iResolution.y;

    // Calculate the color based on plot_implicit values
    vec4 color = vec4(0.);

    color = PLOT_IMPLICIT(curve, uv, RGBA_RED,  color);

    fragColor = color;
}
```

Can anyone suggest an elegant approach to handle these discontinuities and ensure that only the desired portion (continuous part) of the implicit function is plotted?